# Calculating the mean excess loss

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, conditional-expectation, coverage-probability

Suppose $X$ has the following pdf:
 $$ f_x(x)=0.01 \qquad for\space 0\le x<100$$
Find the pdf of $X_p$ (the excess-loss variable) and calculate the mean excess loss for $d=10$.
\begin{align}
P(X_p>x_p)&=P(X-d>x_p|X>d)\\
&=P(X>x_p+d|X>d)\\
&=\frac{S_x(x_p+d)}{S_x(d)}\\
f_{x_p}(x_p)&=-\frac{d}{dx_p}\frac{S_x(x_p+d)}{S_x(d)}\\ 
&=\frac{f_x(x_p+d)}{S_x(d)}
\end{align}

since the support of $x$ and $x_p$ are equal, we can write:
\begin{align}
f_{x_p}(x)&=\frac{f_x(x+d)}{S_x(d)}\\ 
&=\frac{0.01}{1-(0.01)10}\\
&=\frac{0.01}{0.9}\\
E[X_p]&=\int_0^{100}x\frac{0.01}{0.9} dx\\
&=\frac1{0.9}\left(\left.\frac{0.01 x^2}{2}\right|_0^{100}\right)\\
&=\frac{50}{0.9}
\end{align}

The correct answer is $\frac{40.5}{0.9}$. Did i do something wrong? I've tried to calculate the mean excess-loss using $\frac{\int_{10}^{100}S_x(x)dx}{0.9}$ and i got the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without explicitly answering this consider the definition of mean excess loss variable and under what values of x it has a value. Then look at the values you're integrating between.

(you may also want to consider whether you want to be integrating or taking a sum, but that may not change your answer)

Comment: Thanks! The integration part should be integrated from 0 to 90 not from 0 to 100...